# Create a data.frame including ONLY the observations unique to a specific column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

How can I create a `data.frame` including ONLY the observations unique to a specific column (for which values are > 0 and =0 on the rest of the columns.

```
df <- data.frame(column=c("Obs1", "Obs2", "Obs3", "Obs4", "Obs5"), `1`=c(1,2,0,0,1), `2`=c(0,0,0,0,2), `3`=c(0,0,1,0,3), `4`=c(0,0,1,3,4),check.names=FALSE)

df

  column 1 2 3 4
1 Obs1   1 0 0 0
2 Obs2   2 0 0 0
3 Obs3   0 0 1 1
4 Obs4   0 0 0 3
5 Obs5   1 2 3 4

S1_unique <- col1 > 0 and col2:4 = 0 #would include Observations 1 and 2

S34_unique <- col3 and 4 > 0 and col1,2 = 0 #would include Observation 3
```

Comment: Could you clarify how the output should look like in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, though, I renamed all columns from `1`, `2`, ... to `col1`, `col2`, ..., since that's how you refer to them in your pseudo-code.

```r
names(df)[2:5] <- paste0("col", 1:4)
```

New to `dplyr-1.0.0` is the `across` function, useful here.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(col1 > 0, across(col2:col4, ~ . == 0))
#   column col1 col2 col3 col4
# 1   Obs1    1    0    0    0
# 2   Obs2    2    0    0    0
df %>%
  filter(across(col3:col4, ~ . > 0), across(col1:col2, ~ . == 0))
#   column col1 col2 col3 col4
# 1   Obs3    0    0    1    1
```

Comment: Yes, this is it, thanks. The name change was not necessary, but thanks for the extra info :) , this worked without the name changing: ```df1<- df %>%
  filter('1' > 0, across('2':'4', ~ . == 0))```

Comment: Also I will leave in here that in case the columns to filter are not consecutive you can still apply the same code edited ```df4<- df %>%
  filter(across(col2, ~ . > 0), across(col4, ~ . > 0),across(col1, ~ . == 0), across(col3, ~ . == 0)) ```

Comment: That's inefficient (though not an error, nor technically wrong). You can `c(...)` them, as in `filter(col1 > 0, across(c(col2,col4,col3), ~ . == 0))`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, this may give you what you had in mind:

```r
df <- data.frame(column=c("Obs1", "Obs2", "Obs3", "Obs4", "Obs5"), `1`=c(1,2,0,0,1), `2`=c(0,0,0,0,2), `3`=c(0,0,1,0,3), `4`=c(0,0,1,3,4),check.names=FALSE)

library("dplyr")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library("tidyr")

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = `1`:`4`) %>% 
  filter(value!=0) %>% 
  select(-1) %>% 
  distinct(name, value) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(name, id) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id)  %>% 
  select(-id) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>     `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     1     1
#> 2     2     0     3     3
#> 3     0     0     0     4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi @giocomai, thanks for the answer, maybe I should have been more clear with the exact output as I only stated the pseudo-code/ idea. The answer below is what I needed. But thanks for your reply :)